# How could I remove the last character from a string if it is a punctuation, in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, substring

Gah, regex is slightly confusing.

I'm trying to remove all possible punctuation characters at the end of a string:

```
if str[str.length-1] == '?' || str[str.length-1] == '.' || str[str.length-1] == '!' or str[str.length-1] == ',' || str[str.length-1] == ';' 
    str.chomp!
end
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do this. Any pointers?

Comment: Please clarify whether characters like '#', '@', '-', '_' qualify as punctuation in your list of things to remove. How about ':'?

Comment: As of now, only those that I had listed. I believe :punct: includes the rest that you had mentioned, but I was only interested in removing the characters I had listed above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
str.sub!(/[?.!,;]?$/, '')
```

- `[?.!,;]` - Character class.  Matches any of those 5 characters (note, `.` is not special in a character class)
- `?` - Previous character or group is optional
- `$` - End of string.

This basically replaces an optional punctuation character at the end of the string with the empty string.  If the character there isn't punctuation, it's a no-op.

Comment: Simple question: Would str.sub!(/[?.!,;]?$/, '') suffice (and modify str in place) or would I have to set str = str.sub!(/[?.!,;]?$/, '')  instead?

Comment: Since it's using `sub!` it will change the string in place.

Answer (score 2):

The original question stated 'Remove all possible punctuation characters at the end of a string," but the example only mentioned showed 5, "?", ".", "!", ",", ";". Presumably the other punctuation characters such as ":", '"', etc. should be included in "all possible punctuation characters," so use the :punct: character class as noted by kurumi:

```
str.sub!(/[[:punct:]]?$/,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

all non-word characters.

`text.gsub(/\W$/, "")`

what this does is does is looks at the string, finds the punctuation at the end, and globally substitutes with nothing = thus removing it.

This really does work, and it's a ruby way to use regex.

Comment: That regex is totally different from what he asked.  And it returns a new string, rather than modifying the existing one.

Comment: Like rockerest's, this matches spaces as well as punctuation.

Comment: I suppose I was trying to be too intuitive. It seemed to be his next progressive question. My bad.

Comment: I don't think `\w` and `\W` do what you think they do. `\w` includes A-Z, a-z, 0-9 AND `_`, so your test will leave trailing underscores.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a regular expression to do this.  I don't have any experience with ruby, but here's a RegEx that should work:

```
/(.*)[^\w\d]?$/
```

You can use backreference #1 to get the string without the last punctuation character.

Comment: That regex is not what he asked for.  There are many other characters that will match yours, '@' being just one.

Comment: '@' is punctuation... and I think you're abusing the [downvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) privilege.  Please explain how this post was "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect"

Comment: @rockerest, 1. He said he wants a better equivalent of his existing code.  2. Yours also matches things like tab, which is definitely not punctuation.

Comment: @Matthew, my God.  You literally downvoted EVERY other answer.  What a rep whore.

Comment: @rockerest, all the other answers are wrong.  I have no problem upvoting competing answers when they're mostly or completely right.  I explained all my downvotes.  Calling tab and space punctuation *is* clearly incorrect.

Comment: @Matthew "text.gsub(/\W$/, "")" "That regex is totally different from what he asked. And it returns a new string, rather than modifying the existing one."  Ah, yes, having to gather the resulting string is dangerously incorrect, and egregiously sloppy.  You, sir, are a tool.

Comment: @rock, `\W` matches things like space and tab.  Do I really have to convince you those aren't punctuation?  If you read the line you quoted, you'll see "clearly incorrect" is enough.

Comment: [Vote Down](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) "If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it."  Voting down is something you reserve for very poor answers.  **everyone** posts slightly incorrect answers.  That's why you leave a comment and suggest improvements.  It's in the spirit of a community support environment.  It's very clear that you're significantly abusing the downvote privilege.

Comment: I *do* leave comments for my downvotes, which you have in fact quoted back at me.

Answer (score 0):

```
mystring.gsub(/[[:punct:]]+$/,"")
```

Comment: That does one or more character, and punct matches much more than the 5 he listed.

Comment: While this is not what I needed (at this time), thanks for :punct: - I didn't know about it. What are all the punct matches this would match?

Answer (score 0):

Without using the empty string:

```
str = /[?.!,;]?\z/.match(str).pre_match
```

or in the other order

```
str = str.match(/[?.!,;]?\z/).pre_match
```

Answer (score 0):

`str.chomp!` won't do anything in this case. You'd have to do `str.chop!`